# pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource')

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze, setup.py

I have trouble to build my setup.py I got this mistake to each attemps... pywintypes.error: (2, 'BeginUpdateResource', 'Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.')
I can't figure out why and where come from this mistake ? If someone could explain to me I would appreciate and be very greateful !

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        ],
    },}

includefiles = ["logo.ico", "image.gif"]

target = Executable(
    script = "Livre de Compte Bêta.py",
    copyright= "Copyright © 2020",
    icon = "logo.ico",
    base = "Win32GUI")

setup(
    name = "Livre de Compte",
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = "options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}}, executables = [target]",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**instructions:**

1. Change `tcl` and `tk` directory according to your file location
2. Change executable file extension with `.pyw`, this will hide the console window when you will run your `.exe`
3. Remove or add any extra file or folder according to example
4. Simply run `setup.py` according to your need

- Extra Tip: You can design your installer with `inno setup`

You can discuss extra question in comment.

---

You can try this script:

```
    import cx_Freeze
    import sys
    import os
    
    base = None
    
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        base = "Win32GUI"
    
    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Python\Python 3.7\tcl\tcl8.6"  # Path of tcl
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Python\Python 3.7\tcl\tk8.6"  # Path of tk

    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("app.pyw",  # Executable file with .pyw extension
                                        base=base,
                                        icon="Image\shield.ico"  # Path of icon
                                        )]
    
    cx_Freeze.setup(
        name="Name",  # Name of the app
        options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["tkinter", "os"],
                               "include_files": ['tcl86t.dll',
                                                 'tk86t.dll', 
                                                 'Image']}}, # Extra file or folder
        description="Write about your app",
        executables=executables
    )
    
    # Run this command python setup.py bdist_msi, if you want installer and exe
    # Run this command python setup.py build, if you want exe only
```

Comment: Good day, to you. [Read this short guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, I've got two problems, the first one, it doesn't succeed to find tcl86t.dll neither tk86t.dll, so, I used os.path to correct this error. The second, error: [WinError 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable: 'build\\exe.win32-3.8\\name of  the app.exe'. This time I didn't correct the problem... I don't know why it can't find the folder since it have to create the folder...